# Trying to print out a dictionary with index numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

Hiya I am trying to print out a dictionary so it ends up looking like this

```
-------- view contacts --------
    1    Stish        123
    2    Rita         321
```

I have got so far as to print it like this

```
-------- view contacts --------
        Stish        123
        Rita        321
```

But I am unsure as to how I could get it to print with index numbers as well. This is the code I have currently.

```
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    print("-------- view contacts --------") 
    for key, value in contacts.items():
        print ("       ",key,"      ",value)
```

many thanks for the help and please bear with me as I'm pretty inexperienced.

Tried to integrate a for loop with then x+1 for each value but I kept running into concatenation errors as its a string and not an integer that the dictionary values are being stored as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    print("-------- view contacts --------")
    for ix, (key, value) in enumerate(contacts.items()):
        print("{:3}    {:10}  {:8}".format(ix+1, key, value))
```

This produces the following:

```
-------- view contacts --------
  1    Stish            123
  2    Rita             321
```

This uses a fixed width for each field so that they line up properly.
You can adjust the field widths as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This fixed the problems I was having :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```py
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    print("-------- view contacts --------") 
    for index (key, value) in enumerate(contacts.items()):
        print (f"{index}       {key}      {value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another counter element in your for loop, which will be in a range on length of your dictionary.

```py
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    print("-------- view contacts --------") 
    for (key, value), id in contacts.items(), range(1, len(contacts)):
        print (f"    {id}    {key}    {value}")
```

or with enumerate function:

```py
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    print("-------- view contacts --------") 
    for (key, value), id in contacts.items(), enumerate(contacts):
        print (f"    {id}    {key}    {value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

did i answer your question?

```
def viewcontacts(contacts):
    index=0
    print("-------- view contacts --------") 
    for key, value in contacts.items():
        print (index,"   " ,key,"      ",value)
        index+=1
```